# ansible json_query multiple values

Tags: ansible, jmespath, json-query

From a prior `GET` api call in ansible I'm getting a json result back.

The api call would look something like this:

```
- name: Refresh Datadog monitors list
  uri:
    url: http://my.api.com
    return_content: yes
    method: GET
    status_code: 200
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json"
  register: results
```

The result looks something like this (dummy data):

```
[{
    "name": "bob",
    "id": 13590804,
    "colour": "blue",
    "created": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "modified": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "overall_state_modified": "2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00",
    "overall_state": "OK"
},
{
    "name": "john",
    "id": 123124515,
    "colour": "green",
    "created": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "modified": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "overall_state_modified": "2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00",
    "overall_state": "OK"
},
{
    "name": "carl",
    "id": 3252532,
    "colour": "orange",
    "created": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "modified": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "overall_state_modified": "2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00",
    "overall_state": "OK"
},
{
    "name": "louis",
    "id": 5675467,
    "colour": "purple",
    "created": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "modified": "2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00",
    "overall_state_modified": "2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00",
    "overall_state": "OK"
}]
```

In a subsequent step I'm looking to do extract just two values from the json so that it looks something like:

```
[{
        "name": "bob",
        "id": 13590804
    },
    {
        "name": "john",
        "id": 123124515
    },
    {
        "name": "carl",
        "id": 3252532
    },
    {
        "name": "louis",
        "id": 5675467
    }
]
```

I've tried multiple iterations from different sources to try and get this result such as:

```
- name: "Display all id's with names"
  debug: msg = "{{ results | json_query '[id, names]')}}"
```

and

```
- name: "Display all id's with names"
  debug: msg = "{{ results | json_query '[*][id, names]')}}"
```

I can appreciate that there's a gap in my knowledge of jmespath, but the documentation is a bit overwhelming and I'm unable to find the exact solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are looking for the section referenced as [filters and multiselect hashes](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-hashes) in JMESPath documentation.

So your task should be:

```yaml
- name: "Display all id's with names"
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ results | json_query('[*].{id: id, name: name}') }}"
```

---

For the demonstration purpose, given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ results | json_query('[*].{id: id, name: name}') }}"
  vars:
    results: 
      - name: bob
        id: 13590804
        colour: blue
        created: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        modified: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        overall_state_modified: 2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00
        overall_state: OK
      - name: john
        id: 123124515
        colour: green
        created: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        modified: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        overall_state_modified: 2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00
        overall_state: OK
      - name: carl
        id: 3252532
        colour: orange
        created: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        modified: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        overall_state_modified: 2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00
        overall_state: OK
      - name: louis
        id: 5675467
        colour: purple
        created: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        modified: 2019-11-21T07:41:33.148976+00:00
        overall_state_modified: 2019-11-25T06:45:08+00:00
        overall_state: OK
```

This output will be:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - id: 13590804
    name: bob
  - id: 123124515
    name: john
  - id: 3252532
    name: carl
  - id: 5675467
    name: louis
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. I did have a challenge initially but that's because I didn't paste all the output in my question. Final version was: msg: "{{ results.json | json_query('[*].{id: id, name: name}') }}"